# How can I get the parenthesis numbers of a string in Python 3x

Tags: string

I am trying to extract only the numbers that are inside parentheses (), but I have only been able to obtain those that are outside, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
str = "h (3110), 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog (500)"
[int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

**Regards, Thank**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a lib for regex called `re`. It will helps you to find only the digits between parenthesis that you want.

Answer:

```
import re
s = "h (3110), 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog (500)"
l = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\((\d+)\)', s)))
print(l)
```

The regex `\((\d+)\)` creates a group with all digits that appears between parenthesis like that:

[image: state machine]

PS: I change the name `str` to `s` because `str` is a definition for the type `string` in python.